# AWS SQS Cross-Account Private Access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-vpc

I am new to this topic. I am searching how to access AWS SQS in Account B from a VPC in Account A without going trough Internet. I know I can use VPC endpoint and that SQS supports it. But for cross-accoount I cannot find much how to do it. An option I understand is that I could create Endpoint Service in Account B. But this is for Network Load Balancers and Gateway Load Balancers only. So I am wondering if SQS can be put behind a Network Load Balancers or Gateway Load Balancers ? Otherwise what are other options?

Comment: I guess you are referring to privatelink. The privatelink access does not care about cross-account. Just setup the cross-account permissions as normal and set up the privatelink as normal. They should not interfere with each other. At least that is what I would expect. Look at it this way: the privatelink takes care of routing the request, but your request always ends up at the global sqs service and there it is decided wether the request is allowed or not. The routing and the permissions are separate topics.

Comment: ok thanks. So I understand that the privatelink will expose fullly/gloally per-region SQS. Thereafter it is up to me to provide right routing info and proper permission to succed, right?

Comment: That is how I would expect it to work, I am pretty sure that is correct - anything else would be far to complicated to setup / maintain for AWS.

Comment: But it seems there are two ways for the same results depending on the target service. For example for Load Balancer (EC2) is necessary to create an Endpoint Service in the target account, and with this is possible to accept/reject the cross-account access request as well. It does look that the same process is not available for AWS Services like SQS. Why?

Comment: That is a third (and completely unrelated) topic: when you want to host your own application you can make that available through privatelink as well. That is not for the EC2 service itself but if you want to make one of your actual ec2 instances and your program that runs on it available to other vpcs through privatelink. Has nothing to do with what you need to talk to SQS. You should simply setup a "normal" privatelink: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/12/amazon-sqs-vpc-endpoints-aws-privatelink/ and then setup cross account permissions, nothing more, nothing less.